# How to cut short the program?

Tags: c

I want the following code to be cut short less than 100 bytes. I tried all the control statements that i could. So is there any other way?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int t,x;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
        {
            scanf("%d",&x);
    ((x&x-1)==0&&x!=0)?printf("1\n"):printf("0\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is not a "make my code more horrible" service, I'm afraid.

Comment: `main(){int t,x;scanf("%d",&t);while(t--)scanf("%d",&x),puts(x&x-1||!x?"0":"1");}` (and the `include`, of course) are 99 characters…

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
((x&x-1)==0&&x!=0)?printf("1\n"):printf("0\n");
```

use:

```
printf("%d\n",(x&&!(x&x-1))?1:0);
```

Comment: Please don't encourage this sort of question by providing answers...

Comment: @Oli: Why do you say that?

Comment: @ooga: Because the question is terrible, and inappropriate for SO.  Presenting answers in effect legitimises such questions.

Comment: So, no question about obfuscated code on SO? Where should he go then?

Comment: http://www.codechef.com/SMHT2014/problems/SMHTE

the question was asked in this onlive programming event
and i was unable to solve it so i asked the question here on SO